# Java, need help understanding

Tags: java

I am new to Java and having trouble understanding out the output comes out. I know what the output is but I am having difficulty understanding how it came to be, please help.

(Pretend the value for max is 5)

When 5 is the max, the output is

> E  L  L  L  L
>
> G  E  L  L  L
>
> G  G  E  L  L
>
> G  G  G  E  L
>
> G  G  G  G  E

There is nothing wrong with the code, it is just I am having issues on understanding how the output came to be. Im new to this forum so forgive me for anything that may seem wrong or out of place.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

class Lesson_3_Activity_One {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

     int n, k, max; 
     max = scan.nextInt();        /* read value for max */
     for (n = 0; n < max; n++)
     {  for (k = 0; k < max; k++)
        {  if (n > k)
              System.out.print(" G ");
           else if (n < k)
              System.out.print(" L ");
           else
              System.out.print(" E ");
        }
        System.out.println();
     }

   }
}
```

Comment: We also need help in understanding your question.

Comment: What did you not understand in that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So what is the output, what did you expect it to be, and why? Have you tried debugging through the code line by line? Also, it would help if you'd use more conventional formatting for your code, and ensure that it is all actually formatted as code - look at the preview before posting.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Please reread my question, Im sorry if I am bothering you

Comment: @SabirKhan please reread my question, I am sorry to bother you

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops, one nested inside the other.

First, n is 0. For n=0, we start looping through the inner `for`. 
The first time, k is 0. Both k and n are zero, so the console prints 'E'. 
The second time k is 1. n is still zero, so k is larger than n. The console prints 'L'. The third, fourth and fifth time, k is still greater than n, so the console keeps printing 'L's on the first line.

When k is 4, the inner loop is over and we go back to the outer loop. This time n is 1. The inner loop starts again from 0. And so on.

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Im new on this forum and fairly new to coding so I was having a bit of trouble but you really explained it well thank you

Comment: @helloworld - When you declare your love to a lady, it is not conventional to SHOUT at her :-)

Comment: @StephenC, I guess helloworld is just excited - it happens. :)